# A big issue for nonnormal distribution of residuals in this case?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, residuals, qq-plot

I use both histogram and Normal Q-Q plot for the residuals of my regression.

I would say that the histogram shows somewhat symmetric and the mean is around 0.

[image]

On a Q-Q plot, the points seem to fall along a straight line, with slightly longer tail on the right.

[image]

Therefore, I am not sure if it would be appropriate to consider the normality condition to be met. Anyone could provide some ideas on this?

Comment: You may use Kolmogorov Smirnov test or Shapiro Wilk test. See here for example. https://towardsdatascience.com/6-ways-to-test-for-a-normal-distribution-which-one-to-use-9dcf47d8fa93

Comment: I do use Shapiro Wilk Test and it shows that it is not normally distributed (p-value is very small). So, I think it is an issue.

Comment: How large the sample size? It says here that "if the sample size is sufficiently large this test may detect even trivial departures from the null hypothesis (i.e., although there may be some statistically significant effect, it may be too small to be of any practical significance)" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test.

Comment: The sample size is 650.